# Java 3D - bounding sphere

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, bounding

Uhm, what exactly does the bounding sphere in Java 3D do?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/media/j3d/BoundingSphere.html

Answer (score 3):

In general terms (not specific to Java 3D), a bounding object is a "simple" object that is guaranteed to completely enclose some other objects.

By perform relatively inexpensive intersection tests on the bounding object a renderer can avoid performing any expensive intersection tests on any of those enclosed objects.

The bounding object doesn't appear within the scene - its sole purpose is for this optimising away of intersection tests.

For example, I might have a complicated shape made out of thousands of polygons.  In the absence of any other optimisations, I'd have to test *every single* polygon to check whether it's visible or not.  With a bounding sphere, if the sphere isn't "visible", then neither are any of those polygons.

Comment: What is the fundamental importance of the bounding sphere in declaring the light sources in a given scene?

Comment: Ohhhh, i get it... so that means that it reduces the amount of computational complexity especially when talking about scenes.

Answer (score 0):

For every 3D geometry we can calculate a sphere so that all points of the given geometry are inside the sphere. That's a bounding sphere.